# Querying arbitrary data the way DBIx::Class does

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I’ve grown to like the DBIX::Class approach to creating queries a lot - specifically the “hashes make ANDs and arrays make ORs” part.

I’d like to be able to do something similar also on data that does not come from DBI.

Is there a module that does that?

Comment: Could you give an example of "data that does not come from DBI"?

Comment: It could be any array of hashes - for example something that comes from a web based API. Or something that comes from parang the output of a pipe from another program. Granted I could save it to a CSV file and then filter but I’d like to have something that does that on the fly and solves the general problem of filtering the AoH.

Comment: Could you give an example of what this query would look like? Presumably there's no SQL.

Comment: Perhaps use DBIx::Class + [DBD::RAM](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::RAM)?

Comment: that's what I was looking for, thanks - want to make that into an answer?